# Windows Movie Maker can't start

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, windows-movie-maker, windows-live-movie-maker

I've installed Microsoft Movie Maker but when I try to run it, I get the error message:

```
Sorry Movie Maker can't start. Make sure your 
computer meets the minimum system requirements
before trying to start Movie Maker again, and then try
to update the driver for your video card if Movie
Maker still doesn't start.
```

I've checked the requirements on the link on the error message and my laptop meets all of them. (My laptop is a HP EliteBook 8560p running Windows 7 64bit with 4GB ram, quad core processor).

I have also tried to update the graphics drivers by going to the `Device Manager`, `Display Adapters\Standard VGA Graphics Adapter` and selecting 'Update Driver Software...' - Windows reports that the driver software is up to date.

I tried to install a new graphics driver from the HP site, but got an error message about insufficient system requirements :-(

I have run dxdiag.exe which confirms the following:

```
(System tab)
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11

(Display tab)
    Drivers:
        DDI Version: unknown
        Driver Model: unknown
    DirectX Features:
        DirectDraw Acceleration: Not Available
        Direct3D Acceleration: Not Available
        AGP Texture Acceleration: Not Available
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see the following:

> Standard VGA Graphics Adapter

and

> DDI Version: unknown
>
> Driver Model: unknown
>
> DirectDraw Acceleration: Not Available
>
> Direct3D Acceleration: Not Available
>
> AGP Texture Acceleration: Not Available

... I get the impression that you don't actually *have* video drivers installed.  Windows wouldn't be using **Standard VGA Graphics Adapter** if you had the correct video drivers installed.  Of course, if you had booted to Safe Mode, and Windows disabled your video drivers temporarily for the session, *then* it would use them.  Otherwise, it shouldn't.

According to the driver download page from HP, you've got your Intel HD Graphics 3000 for normal usage, and AMD Mobilty Radeon HD 6470M for hard core  (gaming, etc) usage.  So, I would [start here at HP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/ProductList.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5056949), choose which of the three listed fits you, then choose the operating system (not just Win7 64 bit, but which one), and go to Driver - Graphics.  Download both the AMD and the Intel installers, and install both.

Then, see if Movie Maker will work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Installing the AMD drivers did the trick. For some reason I was thinking that I would need the intel drivers since it has an intel processor - the intel drivers failed to install which had me puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same issue on two machines myself.  I resolved this by removing the video driver via Device Manager and be sure to check the box that says to delete the driver. Restart your machine, install the latest driver. Restart again, then test movie Maker and all should be well.