# Movie Maker - System requirements error

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, windows-movie-maker, windows-live-movie-maker

I used to have Movie Maker installed and I used to use it frequently, however I did a fresh install of Windows 7 and since then I've not used it. I wanted to use it Yesterday but couldn't find it, so I ended downloading Windows Essentials 2012 and installed it. Now, however I am facing this error:

[image]

Which is odd because my system specs are more than capable:

[image]

I also tried to update my NVidia driver and had no success, then I completely removed it and reinstalled it through Windows device manager and still no success.

So I tried various suggestions provided by the internet:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled by video driver.
- Ran several Windows patches.
- Installed DirectX 9, 10.
- Ran DirectX Diagnostic Tool and the results are below of the display screen.

[image]

I also so the following question, but it had no relevance as I had a video driver installed.

[Windows Movie Maker can't start](https://superuser.com/questions/577081/windows-movie-maker-cant-start)

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to resolve the issue, though not an ideal fix I had to reinstall the operating system and start afresh, ensure you have the required back-ups so you don't have any data loss issues.